# enviar 2 datos de una vista a otra con react y typescript, con base de datos firebase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

tengo una vista en donde se guardan los datos de un estudiante, entre esos datos esta su nombres = string, y apellidos = string, curso= GradeId que viene de otra coleccion y se juntan en un dropdown cuando se crea, ahora cada estudiante esta vinculado a el curso que se elige en el dropdown, eso es lo que se refleja en la vista de estudiantes.
Tengo una vista de libro de clases en la cual sale cada libro de clases dependiendo del curso, lo que quiero es que cuando apreto un libro de clases me salgan los nombres y apellidos de los estudiantes ingresados a ese curso para asi agregar su asistencia, notas, etc, estas son las vistas

[image: vista de estudiantes]

[image: vista libro de clases]

cuando apreto la estrella se abre una vista y quiero que en esa vista se vean solamente los alumnos ingresados en ese curso, espero alguien me pueda ayudar ya que es para mi proyecto de titulo y estoy estancado hace un buen rato, no entiendo como llamar a esos 2 datos a la otra vista pero filtrando de que curso son.

Saludos